# How to throw exception with stacktrace?

Tags: magento-1, exception

I need my extension to throw an exception which includes a stack trace.

I tried `Mage::throwException('message')` but nothing is logged in `var/log/exception.log` nor at `var/log/system.log` nor in the vhost error log

I am calling the line from a helper class.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the developer console and noticed that it actually works. It is not logged into logfiles but in **var/report**

You just have to open the file with the showed number, in my case `var/report/1315919780090`

[image]